# Why are Cross-Domain Cookies not carried in the new page's ajax request?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, cookies, cors, cross-domain

There are two pages in my front-end demo, `login.html` and `home.html`.
When I click the "login" button in the `login.html`, a Ajax request which carries the username and password will be sent to the back-end. If I log in successfully, the page will jump to `home.html`.

```html
<body>
    <button id="login-btn">login</button>
    <script>
        $('#login-btn').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/login',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'username': 'hover', 'password': 'hover' }),

                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    alert(data.success);
                    // jump to home
                    window.location.href = 'home.html';
                },

                error: function(xhr, error_type, exception) {
                    console.log(error_type);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

There is a "request" button in `home.html`. When I click the "request" button, a Ajax request which carries a "greeting" will be sent to the back-end. If I have logged in, I will receive the echo response, otherwise I will receive a "not yet logged in" message.

To tell the back-end "I have logged in!", I set `withCredentials` to true to make the request carry the cookie which contains `JSESSIONID`.

```html
<body>
    <button id="request-btn">request</button>
    <script>
        $('#request-btn').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/echo',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'greeting': 'hello' }),
                crossDomain: true,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },

                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                },

                error: function (xhr, error_type, exception) {
                    console.log(error_type);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I use SpringMVC to bulid my back-end and I have configured `CORS` and `LoginInterceptor`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    //CORS
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5500")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("content-type", "origin")
                .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(1800);
    }

    // Register the LoginInterceptor
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoginInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/login");
    }
}
```

`LoginInterceptor` will intercept any requests other than `Preflight OPTIONS` and login requests.

```java
public class LoginInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
        // Let OPTIONS pass directly
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the client has already logged in.
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("username") != null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            // {"message": "not yet logged in"}
            response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"not yet logged in\"}");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In `ApiController`, the `login` method prints the username and password, creates a `session` and stores the username, and returns a "success" message.
The `echo` method returns the greeting message from `home.html`.

```java
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/login", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public String login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> param, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = param.get("username");
        String password = param.get("password");
        System.out.println("username: " + username);
        System.out.println("password: " + password);

        // create a session and store the username
        request.getSession().setAttribute("username", username);
        // {"success": true}
        return "{\"success\": true}";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/echo", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public String echo(@RequestBody Map<String, String> param) {
        String greeting = param.get("greeting");
        System.out.println(greeting);
        // {"greeting": "hello"}
        return "{\"greeting\": " + "\"" + greeting + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Because a `session` is created in the `login` method, the header of the response to the login request will have `Set-Cookie` field set to `JSESSIONID`, which is what I want to carry in the `home.html`'s request.

login request images:
[preflight OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSOk3.png)
[POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E71E1.png)

But in reality, when I later jump to `home.html` and send greeting requests, `JSESSIONID` is not carried. Thus I receive the "not yet logged in" message. I wonder why this happens?
images:
[preflight OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeu7c.png)
[POST which does not carry a cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Klv.png)

Answer (score -1):

If I set that in "login" Ajax request as well, the problem will be solved.
Just like the codes:

```
<body>
    <button id="login-btn">login</button>
    <script>
        $('#login-btn').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/login',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'username': 'hover', 'password': 'hover' }),


                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },


                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    alert(data.success);
                    // jump to home
                    window.location.href = 'home.html';
                },

                error: function(xhr, error_type, exception) {
                    console.log(error_type);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

On the face of it, the problem is solved.
Actually, I only want to make the "greeting" Ajax request carry the cookie, but now I have to set `withCredentials` to true in "login" Ajax request as well.
So what's going on behind the scenes?

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests.
> In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are to be ignored in the response. The default is false. XMLHttpRequest from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request. The third-party cookies obtained by setting withCredentials to true will still honor same-origin policy and hence can not be accessed by the requesting script through document.cookie or from response headers.

**In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are to be ignored in the response.**